# jquery fadeout, fadein, wait, fadein again broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to store the content of a div, temporarily display a thank you message, and then put back the original content of div. For some (possibly, many) reasons, it is failing, and I cannot figure out why. What have i done wrong?

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    //store original content
    //appears to be a text string, rather than a jquery object
    var content = $('#container').html();
    console.log(content);
    $('#container').children().fadeOut(800, function() {
        $('#container').html('<div id="thanks">Thanks!</div>', function() {
            $('#thanks').fadeIn(800, function() {

                var t=setTimeout(function(){$('#container').html(content)},3000)

            });
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaZCW/

Comment: What exactly is failing, what error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the html function is synchronous... there's no need for a callback: http://jsfiddle.net/gaZCW/10/

```
$('#container').children().fadeOut(800, function() {
    $('#container').html('<div id="thanks">Thanks!</div>');
    $('#thanks').fadeIn(800, function() {
        $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $('#container').html(content).children().hide().fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, `delay` is going to be cleaner (and more concise) than setting a timeout in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function takes only one argument. So your callback isn't called.

I checked [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) to be sure :

```
html: function( value ) {
```

You may do this :

```
$('#container').html('<div id="thanks">Thanks!</div>');
$('#thanks').fadeIn(800, function() {
     var t=setTimeout(function(){$('#container').html(content)},3000)
});
```

Comment: aha. that makes sense. how could i structure a functional callback in this case? thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a callback ? This call is synchronous and you don't even have distant resources to load.

Comment: I don't have a good explanation. This code fades in 'thanks', but it does not put the originial content in after the 3 second setTimeout. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [I verified it works](http://jsfiddle.net/qNb3w/). I don't know what error you made.

Comment: yeah, i know. I must've mistyped something the first time. Thanks!